# Reducer returns payload correctly but the component receives it as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, redux-thunk

I am implementing an application where I am fetching some data from firebase. The firebase database doesn't require authentication and I already changed the rules for public access.

However, I have a action that fetches a particular row from the database, using the firebase key:

**action**

```
export function fetchClient(id) {
  return (dispatch) => {
     database.ref(`/clients/${id}`)
        .on('value', snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_CLIENT,
            payload: snapshot.val()
        });
     }); 
  };
}
```

Console.log shows the data has been successfully retrieved.

My reducer also returns the payload successfully:

**reducer**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {}

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
 switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_CLIENTS:
        return action.payload;
    case FETCH_CLIENT:
        console.log(action.payload );
        return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case CREATE_CLIENT:
        return action.payload;
    default: 
        return state;
  }
}
```

The component, however receives the payload as undefined when I link to it from the previous page, and is apparently null when I refresh the page.

**component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchClient } from '../actions';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class ClientShow extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
  const { id } = this.props.match.params;
  console.log(this.props);
  this.props.fetchClient(id);
}
render(){
  const { myClient } = this.props;
  if (!myClient) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Link className="btn btn-danger" to="/" >Home</Link>
            <div>Loading...</div>
        </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
        <Link to="/"  className="btn btn-primary" >Home</Link>
        <h2>{myClient.name}</h2>
        <h4>The client is loaded... but undefined</h4>
    </div>
  ); 
 }
}

function mapStateToProps({ clients }, ownProps) {
  //console.log(ownProps.match.params.id);    
  return { myClient: clients[ownProps.match.params.id] };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchClient })(ClientShow);
```

The key in the URL is displayed correctly and from a console.log in the mapStateToProps I receive the correct param.

**Console log**

[image]

**Clients console.log form client_show component**

[image]

Comment: can you please also add the ClientShow component

Comment: hi @enzoborgfrantz, I added the component code.

Comment: can you try console logging clients inside mapStateToProps I believe that it's not actually on the state since you are setting `return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };` on the state and not something like `return { ...state, clients: [] };` but I may be wrong depending on what `[action.payload.id]` contains

Comment: There is no `id` prop in logs you've shown

Comment: @enzoborgfrantz, I did the console log, and I added a screenshot in the question. Actually there's something weird there, I have an extra row which is a copy of the previous one, but with no key.

In line 34 there's also a console log of the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally solved the issue here.

Basically, I was not sending the firebase key form the action to the reducer, expecting to have the id in the action.payload.id.

I now added a new element in my object where I am passing the firebase key:

```
export function fetchClient(id) {
  return (dispatch) => {
     database.ref(`/clients/${id}`)
        .on('value', snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_CLIENT,
            key: id, // Adding the Firebase KEY here
            payload: snapshot.val()
        });
     }); 
  };
}
```

Then, in my reducer:

```
case FETCH_CLIENT:
  return { ...state, [action.key]: action.payload };
```